# Why does the method redirect() accept only one parameter for grails 2.5.x

Tags: grails, groovy

The redirect method of grails can accept just one domain class to redirect to the corresponding 'show' view.

```
book.save flush:true
    withFormat {
        html { 
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), book.id])
            redirect book 
        }
        '*' { render status: CREATED }
    }
```

But the source code

```
  public Object redirect(Object instance,Object object) {
        if(object != null) {

            Class<?> objectClass = object.getClass();
            boolean isDomain = DomainClassArtefactHandler.isDomainClass(objectClass) && object instanceof GroovyObject;
            if(isDomain) {

                Object id = ((GroovyObject)object).getProperty(GrailsDomainClassProperty.IDENTITY);
                if(id != null) {
                    Map args = new HashMap();
                    args.put(LinkGenerator.ATTRIBUTE_RESOURCE, object);
                    args.put(LinkGenerator.ATTRIBUTE_METHOD, HttpMethod.GET.toString());
                    return redirect(instance, args);
                }
            }
        }
        throw new CannotRedirectException("Cannot redirect for object ["+object+"] it is not a domain or has no identifier. Use an explicit redirect instead ");
    }
```

shows that 2 parameters are supposed to be passed to the method. Actually I can only pass the second parameter to the method. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That 2 argument method is one that is invoked by the framework after you invoke `redirect(…)` from a controller.  The first argument will be populated by the `this` (the controller from which you invoked the `redrect` method), not something that you explicitly pass as an argument when you call `redirect(…)`.  I hope that makes sense.

This is similar to the way Groovy extension methods and Categories work.